# How do i generate a random question using javascript for my quiz app which doesn't repeat the same question

Tags: javascript, function, random

I am trying to generate random questions from my "questions" object which does not repeat it's self but my quiz app is repeating questions.

Please forgive me if my question is not clear enough. This is my first ever time asking a question or really using stack overfolow,

```js
let selectedQuestions = [];

//creates random index between 0 and the length of any array passed into it
const getRandomIndex = (arr) => Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);

//uses getRandomIndex to generate select a random object from and array. Also checks to see if the random object has been selected, if not, pushes the question to the empty selectedQuestions array and if selected, loops through its own function with a recursion by calling itself until it finds a question that has not already been pushed to the selectedQuestions array.
const getRandomObject = (arr) => {
  const random = getRandomIndex(arr);
  if (selectedQuestions.includes(random)) {
    getRandomObject(arr);
  }
  selectedQuestions.push(random);
  console.log("selected questions:", selectedQuestions.length)
  return arr[random];

  //renders the selected array and questions in the correct section of the quiz board.
  const randomGenerator = () => {
    const data = getRandomObject(questions);
    progress.textContent = `Question ${gameState.questionCounter} of ${maxQuestion}`
    questionBoard.textContent = `Q${gameState.questionCounter}. ${data.question}`;
    currentCorrectAnswer = data.answer;
    userAnswer.forEach((answer, index) => {
      answer.innerHTML = `${alphabet[index]}. ${data.choices[index]}`;
    });
    currentUserAnswer = null;
    clearAll()

    gameState.questionCounter++
      nextBtn.disabled = true;

    setDisabledStateForQuizAnswers(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: I did a quiz with 10 "random" questions where each of the 10 was taken from 10 categories where each category had 5 questions. No repeats that way. Did not even need any code, just a few random functions on the spreadsheet. worked well.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `return` statement in the `getRandomObject` function.

```
if (selectedQuestions.includes(random)) {
  return getRandomObject(arr);
}
```

Comment: Thank you vary much. I am not sure how i missed that.